# update One2many Record using Write function called from Onchange (Odoo10)

Tags: eclipse, odoo

I am trying to update my One2many record when Onchange method is called. I am fetching the exact value but its not updating the field. Neither I am getting any error.

```
class abc_1(models.Model):
    _name = 'abc.1'                

    field_a1 = fields.Many2one('crm.team',required=True)
    field_a2 = fields.One2many('abc.2', 'field_b1')  

    @api.onchange('field_a1')
    @api.depends('field_a1')
    def get_records(self):    
        for res in self.field_a1.member_ids:
            print res.name 
            self.write({'field_a2':(0,0,'field_b2':res.name})]})    

class abc_2(models.Model):
    _name = 'abc.2'

    field_b1 = fields.Many2one("abc.1")    
    field_b2 = fields.Char(string='Sales Person')
```

I am trying to update records fetched but its not doing anything.

Comment: You are not allowed to `write` during an [`onchange` method](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#onchange-updating-ui-on-the-fly). What is it you are trying to do overall?

Answer (score 4):

First `@api.depends` trigger `onchange` event so you don't need
@api.onchange.

Second don't update the database in onchange event because you will commit
changes to the database what if the user click on cancel button the changes
all ready saved in database.

Third if this code works your querying a lot the database, because any call to write will execute update in database. don't query the database inside a loop only if there is no other solution

Four self.write do not work in `@api.onchange` because the self is not the record is not the real record it's just a dummy record that holds the data  passed from
the client side you can check the `id` you find is always `NewID` object even if the record is saved in database. usually you find the real record in `self._origin` (in new API, or list of ids in old API) in
this you can call write and change the values in database **a danger thing to do**.

```py
@api.depends('field_a1')
def get_records(self):
    # when you use depends, best thing you do is to loop so won't get
    # singleton error
    for rec in self
        # create a list to hold the cammands to create the records
        res_ids = []
        for res in self.field_a1.member_ids:
            # now just add the cammand to the list
            res_ids.append((0,0,{
                'field_b2':res.name,
            })
        # if you will affect only one element just 
        # but if more use rec.update() works like rec.write()
        # but with onchange it don't save data in database.
        rec.field_a2 = res_ids
```